# How to Mage.php file at root folder of project in Magento 2?

Tags: magento

Could you please let me know where is Mage.php file is located in Magento 2? I need to access that Mage.php file in root file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In magento2, there is no Mage.php

It has bootstrap.php performs the main role in Magento 2.

See the code below which helps to call of application:

use `Magento\Store\Model\Store;`

use `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;`

require `YoutmagetoDir. '/app/bootstrap.php';`

```
/* set Parameters for application */

$opt['group'] = 'default';
$opt['standaloneProcessStarted'] = '0';
$params = $_SERVER;
/* you can out your store id here */
$params[StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'admin';
$params[Store::CUSTOM_ENTRY_POINT_PARAM] = true;

/* create application */
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/* the applocation 
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cron $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Cron', ['parameters' => $opt]);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

-createApplication() initialize Magento application

On above example function, we have sent the store code(`PARAM_RUN_CODE`) as admin.

-run() function is execute the application

Answer (score 0):

In /app dir

For example - /public_html/app/Mage.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Mage.php` file in Magento 2 which used to be present under `app/` directory in Magento 1.